# Allow Launching from desktop disappeared from menu

Tags: unity, 20.04, launcher

After some manipulations with .desktop files, the *Allow Launching* option disappeared from the right-click menu of a .desktop file.

How to solve this problem?

Current right-click menu:

[image: Current right-click menu]

Expected right-click menu:

[image: Expected right-click menu]

Comment: What are the permissions on this file? I believe files that have *x* permissions will not have **Allow Launching**.